# C# Visual Studio .NET core - Not finding Nuget-packet type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, console-application, asp.net5

I am creating a `.NET core` (version `1.0.0-rc1-update1`) console application with VS 2015 community (latest version). Building and running the app went fine until I wanted to use any `System.IO` type (can not use `System.Threading` types either).

```
The name 'File' does not exist in the current context
```

I added the `System.IO` package with NPM and it added it to the dependency in the `project.json`. The project itself is running with `dnx` but Visual Studio can not build it.

**project.json**

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [ "Widi" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",

    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "OfcCore": "1.0.0-*",
        "System.IO": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Text.RegularExpressions": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
    },

    "commands": {
        "Ofc": "Ofc"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
        },
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get my project to also build and run in VS?

edit: If I remove `dnxcore50` VS builds like normal. It also seems like it can only not find the `System.IO` and `System.Threading` packages. `System.Text.RegularExpressions` works fine. Is there any special dependency I am missing?

Notes:

- VS Community 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
- ASP .NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)

Comment: Do you have a `using System` at the top of your file?

Comment: @mason on top my cs files - yes VS highlights the types and I also get AC but it is just not building in VS

Comment: What do you mean you added the packages with *NPM*? What VS version are you using (the version is in Help -> About)? Also, from the same About box, share the version of Web dev tools

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci You can add the packages either via NPM, which writes the config to the `project.json`, or you can edit the `project.json` manually. I added them with NPM to make sure they have the latest version. I also edited my question to include product versions.

Comment: Changed the tags, as this discussion was about RC1. Users should now upgrade to RC2, http://dot.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a class is missing, please use http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net to locate the package you should add to project.json. Also you should only put NuGet dependencies under dnxcore50.

Comment: I needed `System.IO.FileSystem` -.-

Comment: @Widi yep. They split large namespaces like System.IO to multiple NuGet packages, so without the search engine it would be quite difficult to find out which to use.